# Finite morphism to Stein manifold

Tags: cv.complex-variables, stein-manifolds

Let $X$ be a complex manifold and let $Y$ be a Stein manifold. Assume that there is a  proper finite holomorphic map $f:X\to Y$ (means that every fiber of $f$ is finite). Can we conclude that $X$ is a Stein manifold?

Comment: Yes. If $\mathscr{F}$ is a coherent sheaf on $X$, $f_*\mathscr{F}$ is coherent and satisfies $H^1(Y,f_*\mathscr{F})=0$. Therefore $H^1(X,\mathscr{F})=0$ for all coherent sheaves on $X$, and this characterizes Stein manifolds.